# The program doesn't stop onto breakpoint in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin, gdb, openocd

Eclipse accidently doesn't stop on breakpoint, but output shows that MCU halted at 0x...., seems that the problem between openocd and arm-none-eabi-gdb

Ubuntu 18, openocd 0.10.0 and arm-none-eabi-gdb from 2016. Earlier it was working. Having this code on my mac, everything works perfectly.

Does anyone have the same issue and and solution for that?

Comment: Did you compile the code with debug symbols?

Comment: yes, I compile with debug symbols and flag -Og